# Is there an algorithm that seek for mathematical link between 3 variables?

Tags: algorithm, math, information-theory

Is it possible to construct an algorithm that look for the most parsimonious (the question of what is parsimonious might seem a bit arbitrary in this case!) formula that link three variables?

For example, given:

```
a = -2, 1, 4, 3.2
b = 1, 2, 7, 0.2
c = 0, 3, 16386, 3.261915
```

the most parsimonious link between these three variables is (Hope this is the most parsimonious):

```
a^b + 2 = c
```

Because:

```
-2^1 + 2 = 0
1^2 + 2 = 3
4^7 + 2 = 16386
…
```

My questions are:

- Is it possible to construct such an algorithm?
- Do you know an already existing algorithm of this kind?

  - If yes, does it work well (quick) for relatively easy relationship as in my example?

---

Update:

Here is a R code that creates 3 variables `a.l`, `b.l` and `c.l` in order to make an example.

```
set.seed(12)
a.l = round(runif(20, -100, 100), 2)
b.l = round(runif(22, -100, 100), 2)
c.l=c()
for (a in a.l){for (b in b.l){c.l[length(c.l)+1] = a^2 + 1.2*b - 8}}
```

Comment: Are `^` and `+` supposed to be mathematical operations or floating-point ones? I do not think that `3.2 ^ 0.2 + 2 = 3.261915` holds in mathematics, yet you say that you are looking for exact equalities in a comment.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Do you mean that `3.2 ^ 0.2 + 2 = 3.261915` is just an approximation of a real value? well, yes. I updated my post in order to have only exact values.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [relational abstract domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation#Examples_of_abstract_domains).

You need to know what you are looking for, if only because without this restriction, there are several solutions. You define “parsimonious” when you chose the abstract domain. Your example has four points and three variables, and there are plenty of other equations, some of them arguably simpler than “a^b…” that define a surface of the 3-dimensional space that passes through these four points.

You may also be looking for [regression analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis), but this requires you to choose the shape of relation you are looking for in an even stronger sense than abstract domains do.

Comment: Regression analysis allows to look for best approximations of these points. I am looking for exact results (R-square = 1). I never heard about relational abstract domains. Indeed, I don't have enough point relationship. If I extend the list of relationship, could you provide an example of how to find out a formula with "minimum number of polynomial" (for example) as a definition of parsimony? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Remi.b “R-square = 1” -> Hence, “even stronger sense”. More generally, my knowledge is limited to knowing that I need to type “abstract domain polynomial” in Google, knowledge the above answer has already transferred to you. It turns up http://www2.in.tum.de/~seidl/papers/poly.ps which for some reason I can't download at this time. Happy reading.

Comment: @Remi.b By the way, you may find that “M. Karr. Affine Relationships Among Variables of a Program. Acta Informatica, 6:133–151, 1976.” is a good introduction to the topic, free of modern refinements, but you will have to get it from a library. Scan it and put it online if you find it, the world will thank you.